# I got a problem during parcel instalation. timeout error / possible compability issues

Tags: npm, parcel

I'm trying to install parcel to tutorial project but it is not working on my temporary laptop.
The message i recive is this

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Programowanie\Forkify> npm i parcel@2
npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@parcel%2freporter-cli (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-05T14_29_15_875Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Programowanie\Forkify>
```

I Dont know if its an issue with not the latest node.js 13.14.0 (npm 6.14.4) Win7 (old laptop)
Becouse this problem is not occuring on my standerd computer with win10 and newest node.